# Don't know why I am getting an alert! 'undefined' message

Tags: javascript

I am learning PHP, JavaScript. The code that follows comes from a textbook that I am using.

```
<script>
function validate(form)
    {
    fail  = validateForename(form.forename.value)
    fail += validateSurname(form.surname.value)
    fail += validateUsername(form.username.value)
    fail += validatePassword(form.password.value)
    fail += validateAge(form.age.value)
    fail += validateEmail(form.email.value)

    if   (fail == "") return true
    else { alert(fail); return false } 
    }
<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <th colspan="2" align="center">Signup Form</th>
    <form method="post" action="adduser387.php" onSubmit="return      validate(this)">
<tr><td>Forename</td> ....
```

The validate functions work. When all fields are validated and I 'submit', the logic falls through to 'else { alert(fail); return false }' giving me an 'undefined' message - not sure why. Please let me know if I provided insufficient info. I could not find an answer on the Internet. Thanks.

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: Define `fail=''` at the beginnig of the function `validate` because `alert(undefined=='')` will return `false`

Comment: How are the other functions defined? What possible values can they return to be assigned or added to `fail`? Do they all `return` a value in all cases?

Comment: It is most likely that one of your validate functions is returning `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Your `js` function has to be like this:

```
function validate(form) {
        var fail = '';
        fail += validateForename(form.forename.value);
        fail += validateSurname(form.surname.value);
        fail += validateUsername(form.username.value);
        fail += validatePassword(form.password.value);
        fail += validateAge(form.age.value);
        fail += validateEmail(form.email.value);

        if (fail == "") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert(fail);
            return false
        }
    }
```

> Problem with your script is `fail` is not defined anywhere hence its value is `undefined`(not considering your filed validation functions return value), hence value if `fail == ""` will never be `true` as `undefined` is not equals to `''` and thats why your else condition is getting satisfied. As there is `undefined` value in `fail`, you are getting alert as `undefined`

Comment: I cheated by commenting out the 'alert' part of the codes and it works fine. However, that is not a solution. I will try your suggestion tomorrow. It is now 1:45 AM. Thanks to all who helped. JohnD